# Render FileStream from another actionResult in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Suppose I have an action in a controller like:

```
public class ChartController
{
   public ActionResult RenderChart(string chartType)
   {    
       ...
       return File(imgStream, "image/png");
   }
}
```

How can I render this action from a different action like

```
public ActionResult MakePDF()
{
    byte [] image = ReadStream("Chart/RenderChart?chartType=LineChart");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do the same logic you are doing in the RenderChart action to obtain the `imgStream` in the MakePDF action as well?

Comment: I would like to make the chartController more versatile and could be used in other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the logic that gets the `imgStream` for a given `chartType` into a common service that both actions can call.

```
public class ChartService
{
    public Stream GetChartImageStream(string chartType)
    {
        Stream imgStream;
        //assign a value to imgStream
        return imgStream;
    }
}
```

If the actions are in the same controller, you can cheat by calling the `RenderChart` method directly. I would still recommend moving the logic into a common service method.

```
public ActionResult MakePDF()
{
    FileStreamResult renderChartResult = (FileStreamResult)RenderChart("LineChart");
    Stream imgStream = renderChartResult.FileStream;
}
```

Comment: I think it is a good way to go. Thanks. I just wonder if there would be some solution based on a controller rather than a service.